# php отправка сообщений

Tags: php, mysql

Столкнулся с проблемой, при попытке записать в базу данных сообщение содержащее символ ' сообщение до базы не доходит. Но ' как я понял, считается как кавычка в следствии чего выходит ошибка. Помогите исправить

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO s_chat SET author_id='".$user['id']."', message='".$mess."', datetime='".$date."', random_id='".$random_id."'");
```

Comment: Для начала надо в ужасе выкинуть mysql_query и использовать mysqli

Comment: Спасибо что закрыли, я же получить то, что мне нужно, ага.